# RPM Signing using X.509 certificates

Tags: x509, codesign

Is there any way to sign a RPM package using X.509 certificate.

Usually RPM packages are signed using GPG keys, but I have an existing workflow that uses X.509 certificates to sign packages and I wanted to reuse that

Answer (score 1):

RPM can be signed using x509 cert but there is  no way to verify this signature using yum or rpm . Although signature can be checked using openssl itself .